# A button that updates it's status to every viewer of a webpage?

Tags: html, web, raspberry-pi, refresh

This is my problem:

- I have a webpage hosted in a raspberry PI
- It is being viewed by 2 clients in different parts of the internet
- On the page there is a button that when clicked, should turn green
- If USER_A clicks it, I want both USER_A and USER_B to see it turning green "at the same time"

What tools should I use to accomplish this?

I mean that I don't want USER_B to refresh the page manually to see the effect.

---

With the help given I've found this: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

May be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some form of "back end" or storage for your web page. Whether it's a simple file on the pi or a database.

Then each page should use some client side script like JavaScript to check the "Button Status" and set the colour based on that on a timed interval of a second or two.

There would need to be some static data store for the current status of the button.

---

With the help given I've found this: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

May be helpful for others.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark McGookin. So it's basically storing the button status on the server and it will be the client who asks the server: What is the button status? - Via Javascript. Am I getting it right?

Comment: That's one approach, but it's not recommended as you would keep pinging the server regardless of change in status. Look into [COMET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) which allows the web server to push data to the browser. With that said, your project seems fairly small and of hobby nature, so whatever works I guess. Good luck!

Comment: Janne Klouman, thanks a lot for the input. It is small yes. It will just put a temperature alarm in maintenance mode or in active mode. But it has to be as simple as possible for the webpage visitor. Also, the two users won't have communication with each other in the moment they visit the page. Hence the need for them to know if the other already placed the alarm in maintenance mode.